# Ignore connection checking in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have defined my database connectivity in database.php. I have 4-5 connections. Some are remote IP's. Problem occours when some IP goes down, i can access my application. Is there a work around for this i.e. application should work even if some IP connectivity is not there.

Comment: try to make changes in the core library files of database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PDO, put inside a try.

If you are using mysql_connect use an IF to check the connection

Comment: database.php is autoloaded.

Comment: Try:
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE; 
$db['default']['autoinit'] = FALSE;

and connect manually